# Responsive Website

Tags: html, css-float, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a simple responsive site.

For the most part everything is working. But as soon as I start to shrink the site, the YouTube video gets bumped onto the next row. Is there a way to fix this so it stays aligned with the ad to the left?

Here is a link to the demo site:
http://ctrice.ca/test/rwd/

**This is the css I'm using.**

```
#ad{ width:100%; max-width:288px; min-height:330px; margin-right:2%; float:left; }

#trailer{ width:100%; max-width:540px; min-height:330px; position:relative; float:left; }

#trailer iframe,
#trailer object,
#trailer embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**This is the HTML code:**

```
<div id="ad"><img src="img/ad.jpg" alt="ad" /></div>

<div id="trailer">
<iframe width="460" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C4uOSz1Z9GM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: You should also have an container for floating elements.

Comment: You're going to have to think through how exactly you want the site to respond to smaller screen sizes. Do you really want the ad and the video to remain side-by-side on one row (is that what you mean by "aligned"?)? If so, you must want the ad to shrink as well as the video -- should proportions change? (Consider how small both the ad and the video will end up on a phone.) If not, then which block do you want on top on a small screen: the ad or the video?

Comment: @daveclark I want them to be aligned until it reaches 768 pixels at least. But it wraps to next line right away as soon as I start shrinking the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will lie with the iframe. I wish I could remember all the gory details but it's best to get that lesson from an expert by Googling for [Scott Jehl and "responsive and responsible"](http://scottjehl.com/) videos and any articles you can find (of which there are many). His specific problem was with ads delivered to the Boston Globe via iframes. Your problem may be that the video is in an iframe.

I know we're not to give answers as "Google for it" but my answer points to the iframe and the many points made by Jiehl are best left to him.

Comment: Even when I takee the youtube embed code out of the #trailer div, it still pops to the new row when I start to resize the page.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me.  The percentage in CSS is found when you divide the height by the width of your video.

(HTML)

`<div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="YourVideoURL" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>`

(CSS)

`/*/V I D E O * W R A P P E R/*/

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe,
.videoWrapper embed,
.videoWrapper object {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}`
```

Hope it works for you good luck!